# It is possible to create a hyperlink to the JS debugger in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The webconsole from FF outputs a hyperlink to the js debugger/source when an error/warning occurs. Is it possible to create such a link in my own devtools extension. And when yes, how?

[image: Link to source]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, what's the chrome url of that page?

Set it in here:

```
var sa = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-array;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsArray);
var wuri = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsString);
wuri.data = 'about:blank';
sa.AppendElement(wuri);
let features = "chrome,dialog=no";

var XULWindow = Services.ww.openWindow(null, 'chrome://global/content/viewSource.xul', null, features, sa);
XULWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {

}, false);
```

Set `wuri.data = 'about:blank';` to the url of whatever sites source you want to load.

Comment: How can I pass information from the devtools page to the addon backend? I´m not able to find a working solution?

Comment: Do so through that `nsISupportsArray`, as I pass to it the URL of the page for which I want to see the source for. I used `about:blank`. You can pass more data, just add to that array but I don't know how it handles more data you have to look into the code of the URI you load into the window, so in this case you would look at the code of `viewwSource.xul`

Comment: I think I did not formulated my question clear enough, sorry. I didn´t want to show the source of my extension. I like to create such a link for specific scripts from an inspected web site. So I have to register a click handler in the devtools page which sends a message to the addon backend and execute your code example.